# integral $\frac {\overline{f(z)}}{z-a}$ and Cauchy formula

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Problem:Let $f(z)$ be analytic on some domain containing the closed unit disk $|z|\leq1$. Calculate
$$\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_D\frac{\overline{f(z)}dz}{z-a}$$ if $|a|<1$, where D is unit circle.

Solution:
Let$$f(z)=u(z)+iv(z)$$
where, $u,v$ are real functions.
By Cauchy integral formula we have:
$$\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_D\frac{f(z)dz}{z-a}=f(a)$$
so,

$$\int_D\frac{(u(z)+iv(z))dz}{z-a}=2 \pi if(a)$$
$\int_D \frac {u(z)}{z-a}dz=-2 \pi Im(f(a))$ and $\int_D \frac {u(z)}{z-a}dz=2 \pi Re(f(a))$.
So,
$$\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_D\frac{\overline{f(z)}dz}{z-a}=\frac{1}{2 \pi i}(-2 \pi Im(f(a))-i2 \pi Re(f(a))=- \overline{f(a)}$$
What is wrong with this solution( in book solution is $\overline{f(a)}$)?

Comment: First of all, fix the statement. You're not integrating over the whole disk. You're integrating over the unit circle? And you need $|a|<1$, not $|a|\le 1$?

Comment: You have a typo in an equation. It should read: $\int_D \frac {v(z)}{z-a}dz=2 \pi Re(f(a))$. Also, as a hint, if you have a complex function $z = r e^{i \theta}$ where $r \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$, then computing $\overline{z}$ effectively reverses the trajectory over the circle for $z$. Namely, as $\theta$ increases, while $z$ traverses the circle *counterclockwise*, $\overline{z}$ traverses the circle *clockwise*. When you reverse the direction of traversal of a contour integral you get a minus sign.

Comment: You need to fix the statement as Ted has suggested. $D$ is the full open disc. That can't be what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g$ is holomorphic on $D(0,R), R>1,$ then

$$\tag 1 g(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} g(e^{it})\,dt.$$

This falls right out of Cauchy's theorem (or the mean value property of harmonic functions if you like).

Do a little work to see our expression equals

$$\tag 2 \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ \overline{f(e^{it})}}{1-ae^{-it}}\,dt = \overline{ \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{f(e^{it})}{1-\bar{a}e^{it}}  }\,dt.$$

If we let $g(z)=f(z)/(1-\bar{a}z)$ and use $(1),$ we see that $(2) $ equals $\overline{f(0)}.$